# Getting String from Getline (streamed from a text file) and inserting into linkedlist / trie

Tags: c++, string, readfile, getline, trie

I'm having some troubles with searching a string inserted into a trie. I find that if I insert using a string literal, my trie has no issues with finding the word. But if it is streamed from a file, then it cannot do so. I have a suspicion it may have to do with a null terminator, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

My Code is below:

trie.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class Node {
    public:
        Node();                           
        ~Node();                          
        char  Content();                   // Returns mContent
        void  SetContent(char c);          // Set Node content to char c
        bool  WordMarker();                // A boolean flag if a word has formed
        void  SetWordMarker();             // Sets Word marker in Node
        void  AppendChild( Node* child );  // Appends an element into array
        Node* FindChild(char c);           // Locates character and returns Node

        //vector<Node*> children( { return mChildren; }
        //Node *children() { return mChildren

    private:
        char mContent;
        bool mMarker;
        vector<Node*> mChildren;
};

class Trie {
    public:
        Trie();
        ~Trie();
        void AddWord(string s);           // Adds string to the trie 
        bool SearchWord(string s);        // Finds word in trie
    private:
        Node* root;
};
```

trie.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "trie.h"
using namespace std;

Node::Node()                        { mContent = ' '; mMarker = false; }
Node::~Node()                       {}
char Node::Content()                { return mContent; }
void Node::SetContent(char c)       { mContent = c; }
bool Node::WordMarker()             { return mMarker; }
void Node::SetWordMarker()          { mMarker = true; }
void Node::AppendChild(Node* child) { mChildren.push_back(child); }

Trie::Trie()    { root = new Node(); }
Trie::~Trie()   {}

Node* Node::FindChild(char c) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < mChildren.size(); i++ ) {
        Node* tmp = mChildren.at(i);
        if ( tmp->Content() == c ) {
            return tmp;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}


void Trie::AddWord(string s) {
Node* current = root;

if ( s.length() == 0 ) {
    current->SetWordMarker(); // an empty word
    return;
}    
if ( SearchWord(s) ) {
    cout << s << " already exists in Trie. Skipping." << endl;
    return;
}
for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ) { 
        Node* child = current->FindChild(s[i]);
        if ( child != NULL ) {
            current = child;
        } else {
            Node* tmp = new Node();
            tmp->SetContent(s[i]);
            current->AppendChild(tmp);
            current = tmp;
        }
        if ( i == s.length() - 1 ) {
            current->SetWordMarker();
        }
    }
}

bool Trie::SearchWord(string s) {
    Node* current = root;

    while ( current != NULL ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ) {
            Node* tmp = current->FindChild(s[i]);
            if ( tmp == NULL ) {
                return false;
            }
            current = tmp;
        }

        if ( current->WordMarker() ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <set>

#include "trie.h"
#include "trie.cpp"

std::set <char> CharSet ( char oldArr[4][4], const int n ) { 
    std::set <char> uniqueCharSet;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
            uniqueCharSet.insert( oldArr[i][j] );
        }
    }
    return uniqueCharSet;
}

void LoadTrie( std::set <char> charSet, int limit ) {
    Trie *trie = new Trie();
    std::string filename = "enable1.txt";
    std::string word;
    std::ifstream dict1;
    dict1.open( filename, std::ios::in );
    if( dict1.is_open() ) {
        bool wordInCharSet = false;
        int i = 0;
        int wordLength = 0;
        while( getline( dict1, word ) ) {
            wordLength = word.length();
            wordInCharSet = IsWordInCharSet( charSet, word);    
            if ( wordLength <= limit && wordInCharSet && i < 10 ) {
                std::cout << "Inserting: " << word << endl;
                trie->AddWord( word );
                i++;

                std::cout << "Searching for " << word << "\n";
                if (trie->SearchWord(word) ) {
                    std::cout << "Found " << word << " \n";
                } else {
                    std::cout << "NOT FOUND " << word << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << i << " words with <= " << limit << " characters transferred\n";
    }

    std::string newTestWord = "AHA!";
    trie->AddWord(newTestWord);
    std::cout << "Searching for " << newTestWord << "\n";
    if (trie->SearchWord(newTestWord) ) {
        std::cout << "Found " << newTestWord << " \n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND " << newTestWord << "\n";
    }

    dict1.close();
}

int main( int agrc, char *argv[] ) {
    char matrixArr[4][4] = {{'s','t','n','g'},
                            {'e','i','a','e'},
                            {'d','r','l','s'},
                            {'s','e','p','o'}};

    std::set<char> charSet = CharSet ( matrixArr, 4 );
    LoadTrie ( charSet, 16);

    return 0;
}
```

Enable1.txt

```
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
aardvark
```

My results:

```
Inserting: aa
 ound aa
Inserting: aah
 ound aah
Inserting: aahed
 ound aahed
Inserting: aahing
 ound aahing
Inserting: aahs
 ound aahs
Inserting: aal
 ound aal
Inserting: aalii
 ound aalii
Inserting: aaliis
 ound aaliis
Inserting: aals
 ound aals
Inserting: aardvark
 ound aardvark
10 words with <= 16 characters transferred
Searching for aah
NOT FOUND aah
```

As you also notice, I'm missing the first character 'F' when displaying my results. Why is this? What's going on? Is this a string literal vs c-string?

Comment: Was the input file created on Windows, but you're not running the program on Windows?

Comment: You suspect problems with your `getline()` reading and / or your `triemap` insertions. You also have an unidentified problem with your output. The first step -- done *before* posting here -- is to take your program apart, trying to *isolate* the problems, so you can post a question like "why isn't `getline` not working as expected?", or "why does this insertion not work?", or "why is this not generating the expected output?", with a [*minimal* piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As is, the code you posted doesn't even compile (lacking headers).

Comment: DevSolar: My apologies, this is the first time I'm posting on StackOverflow. I've included the headers, so it should compile without issues now. In regards to your other comment, I've narrowed down the issue as far as I know how to. I noticed when I outputted the string.length() of and the string literal the string from the ifstream, they're different lengths. This has me thinking it may have something to do with the Null Terminator.

Molbdnilo: I'm not sure which OS created the input file. It's the scrabble dictionary enable1.txt found on google: http://bit.ly/1hrlqCH